# Como posso alterar ícone de uma aplicação desktop java no Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

É possível alterar o ícone de uma aplicação desktop java no eclipse ao invés de ficar com o ícone default?

Comment: É uma aplicação Android ou Desktop?

Comment: É uma aplicação Desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema em conseguir trocar o ícone é por que sua aplicação Java para Desktop gera um `.jar`, e diferentemente de arquivos com extensão `.exe` o `.jar` não possui ícone próprio, seu ícone é o mesmo para todos os `.jar` do sistema, portanto você não consegue mudar o ícone dele da mesma forma que faz com o `.exe`.

A solução que eu sugiro é criar um atalho e definir o ícone do atalho, o `.jar` você deixa escondidinho em uma pasta do sistema, e torça para que o usuário nunca resolva fuçar nela.

Agora, se você se refere ao ícone da janela e da barra de tarefas pode mudar assim:

```
frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("img\\logo.jpg"));
```

Por exemplo:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class JanelaComIcone extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JanelaComIcone frame = new JanelaComIcone();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("img\\logo.jpg"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public JanelaComIcone() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }
}
```

A pasta `img` você põe na raiz do projeto.